# AWS multiple VPN client certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

Using AWS I need to make sure I have multiple clients using the VPN network. Each of the clients will use the same server certificate I created earlier.

Now using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/authentication-authorization.html) documentation I managed to setup my own VPN and been able to connect to it using the generated client certificate. This is of course for just one client. I need this done for 3. I cannot share the same client certificate between them as I want to be able to revoke the certificate per person.

Whilst configuring the VPN endpoint I noticed that I had to use "Mutual Authentication" since we have no AD nor will we set one up. This requires you to provide a client certificate when creating the endpoint.

The documentation for generating the certificates and keys states this:

> You only need to upload the client certificate to ACM when the Certificate Authority (Issuer) of the client certificate is different from the Certificate Authority (Issuer) of the server certificate.

Since I just created both (client and server) using the easyrsa steps as mentioned by amazon itself, I find myself unable to create an endpoint when I don't have a client certificate uploaded to the ACM, regardless of it apparently not being required to upload.

Does this actually mean that I need to setup N different endpoints (for each user) when I want to have them use their own certificates? This to me sounds a pretty heavy task, especially provided you have more than 3 users. The documentation is mentioning this:

> You can create a separate client certificate and key for each client that will connect to the Client VPN **endpoint**.

(emphasis mine)

Notice the single "endpoint" as opposed to the plural? Can anyone shed some light on what I might be missing?

Comment: I agree with your understanding. Each of the 3 client certs should be able to connect to the same end point, without needing to upload each client cert to ACM. Are you not able to confirm that behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using Mutual Authentication option for your VPN,  (with the limitations  regarding the same issue in CA)  then yes, each of the 3 client certs should be able to connect to the same end point, without needing to upload each client cert to ACM.

Comment: Alright. That sounds promising. However, when configuring a VPN endpoint I am required to supply a client certificate, which must be provisioned in ACM. Which one then should I choose to create it? Would it for exaple work if I selected and uploaded just a random one of the 3 generated client certificates? Or should I (contra-intuitively) use the server certificate as the client certificate again?

Comment: You can certainly use the server certificate.  I would try that as it would potentially have a longer lifespan than any particular client certificate, in regard to potential future client cert revocations or rotations.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Your suggestion worked Rodrigo. I will mark this answer as correct.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is to embed the client certificate and key into the .ovpn configuration file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58722161/1149414